# Async Lamblda Expression in Razor page of Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, razor, async-await, blazor-server-side

I have an async method in razor page of a blazor server app.

What I am trying to achieve is as below but of course await requires async. How can I `await` async method here?

```
@{
    var result = await Test(local);    
    <div>
        @result
    </div>
}
```

This does not work. It says "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type".

```
<div class="line">
    @(async (local) => { await Test(local); })
</div>
```

Comment: In a comment you to Shahids answer you spoke of a grid context. Please add that information to your question, as it is relevant. What does Test do that it needs to be async and also be done for every single row in your grid?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use component life cycle events. You can to do something like

```
<div class="line">
    @result
</div>

@code{
    private string result;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        result = await Test(local);
    }
}
```

See Blazor documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: unfortunately this piece of code is inside a row template of a grid. There are hundreds of row in a grid. It is not a single call of that async function.

Comment: Okay, that changes the question. See Blazor documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-5.0. If you are on .net50 then try Virtualize else use the traditional foreach approach.

Answer (score 0):

As Shahid Said -

> It's better to use component life cycle events.

But there are some edge cases where lifecycle events wont work.
There isn't a lot of information to work off here but I'll make some assumptions.
Assuming it is absolutely necessary not to use the components life cycle you can use in your HTML Body:

```
@foreach(YourRowObject Row in Table)
{
   <div>
      @Test(Row.Local).Result
   </div>
}
```

And i assume you have a C# code block or CS file that does something like:

```
@code{
    private YourTable Table {get; set;}
    private async Task<string> Test(string local)
    {
        return await SomeApiCall(local);
    }
}
```

This should display the information you are after. Tweak it to fit your application :)

EDIT: Improved code to remove unnecessary var assignment

Comment: Are you sure that calling `Result` on a `Task` is safe in this context?

Comment: You may run into some [AggregateException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-5.0) issues if the task is not handled correctly

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said said, it is better to hook into the page lifecycle events.

Like yourself, I needed to pass a value to rows of a grid/table, but computing the value had to be done asynchronously. I was using a 3rd party grid control so using the `Virtualize` component pattern wasn't a good fit. Since my entities have a unique `Id` property, I worked around it by building up a map ahead of time, then referencing it from the UI code. Here I'm computing a boolean since I was using the value to control whether the user could edit the given row or not, but perhaps you're after a string or some other type.

```
Dictionary<string, bool> enabledMap;
List<RowEntry> entries = new();

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    entries = await GetData();
    foreach(RowEntry entry in entries)
        enabledMap[entry.Id] = await GetValue(entry)
}
```

Then when you need to render, just pull values from the map. This approach also works if you're working with a component that takes the value as a parameter. In my case I was using the bool to control the `Enabled` parameter of my component.

```
@foreach(RowEntry entry in entries)
{
   <MyComponent Data=entry Enabled=enabledMap[entry.Id] />
}
```